# Javascript: document innerHTML replace breaks forms

Tags: javascript, forms, replace, innerhtml

I'm currently trying to replace a piece of plain text in a page that also contains a form. I am aware that upon replacing code containing a form, the form elements get recreated. This can break forms (and it does on the webpage I'm manipulating).

Usually, I go about this by using the "getElementsByTagName" function, to make sure that I don't need to replace the code containing the form and this has always been possible so far. However at this point, I have arrived at a page where the smallest tagname is a div that contains the text I need to replace **and** a form. This div is further subdivided in tables so initially I thought "let's get elements by table", but exactly the piece that I need to replace is **not** subdivided in a table.

So I used this code to replace:

`document.documentElement.innerHTML = document.documentElement.innerHTML.replace(RegEx, replaceString);`

Of course, this breaks the form on the page, which is not wanted behavior.

Does anyone have any idea how to go about this without breaking the form? Is it possible to somehow get a reference to the part of the div that does not contain a table? Is it possible to alter just part of the code? Right now I take an instance of the code, replace the matches in the instance, and then overwrite the original code with the altered instance. I once remember trying `document.documentElement.innerHTML.replace(RegEx, replaceString);` on another page but this only returned an instance of altered code, it did not alter the original code.

This is part of the page:

```
<div class="BoxContent" style="background-image:url(http://static.tibia.com/images/global/content/scroll.gif);">
<TABLE></TABLE>
<BR>
Some text here.
<BR>
And some more.
<table></table>
<table></table>
</div>
```

I need to do some changes in the text between the tables.

I have looked around on SO and found similar question about adding things to a form with innerHTML, but this did not help my cause. So, all help is appreciated here!

Kenneth

Comment: Please tell us what you are trying to accomplish instead of asking us to fix faulty code. Perhaps your actual goal can be achieved without replacing HTML with RegEx which is a bad idea

Comment: First sentence of my question: "I'm currently trying to replace a piece of code in a page that also contains a form."

Essentially, I need to search the page for a certain pattern and if I get the match, I need to replace part of that match by something else. Consider a piece of text containing the word "foo" and I need to replace it with "bar" once. There is no other way of searching the `document` other than searching through the whole page, because the text is not wrapped by any kind of tag, but the replacement could also be done string-wise, not necessarily DOM-wise.

Comment: That is not what I asked. I read your text and saw what you have tried. But WHY do you need to replace some code using script? And why not use jQuery or DOM manipulation like document.getElementsByTagName('form') for example

Comment: There might be a misunderstanding. I'm actually trying to replace a **string of letters**, not HTML code as such. I want to linkify a word inside the text that this page contains to link to another page (for personal easy access purposes).

I tried a JQuery approach with one of my friends, but the problem persists.

The only Tagname that would grab this piece of text is a <div> with class "BoxContent", but this div still contains the forms that get broken when I do the replace. There is no way to narrow it down more. Everything is inside tables in this div, except for this piece of text.

Comment: I have added the relevant piece of the source to the original question. Will the text in this example be returned in one of the childNodes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here - plain JS

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/azU7E/)

```
window.onload=function() {
  var nodes = document.getElementsByClassName("BoxContent")[0].childNodes;
    for (var i=0,n=nodes.length;i<n;i++) {
        if (nodes[i].nodeType==3) {
            // console.log(nodes[i].textContent)
            nodes[i].textContent=nodes[i].textContent.replace(/some/gi,"Lots");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Works too perfection. :) Thanks!